# Displaying wp menus by name without using theme locations

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, navigation

I used wp menus in the past but always registering a location and then using:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

To display a menu on that location on my theme I would first create a menu, and then assign it to that location.

Well now what I would like to do is to create all the menus I want using some standard name like my-menu-1, my-menu-2, my-menu-x. And then I want to display those menus on my theme but without using any location, just printing them using code identifying them by name.

**How could I do that?**

Comment: General notice: If you are developing a theme for distribution, **you should use theme location not menu name.** [See this post by Chip Bennett](http://make.wordpress.org/themes/2012/03/16/custom-menus-implementation-use-theme_location-instead-of-menu-in-wp_nav_menu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm u can do that easily. And this is the way I do

how i register my menu in functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_menu'); 
function register_custom_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('custom_menu', __('Custom Menu'));
}
```

Then in ur admin panel u create different menu by ur desired name. And get the menu where ever u want like this. EX:- if I made two menu in admin by name "Menu 1" and "Menu 2"

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Menu 1'));
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Menu 2'));
```